# Export each sheet from Excel to each pdf page

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

I want to export specified Excel sheet to specified page on PDF. For example, Sheet1 from Excel to Page1 on PDF. Sheet2 from Excel to Page2 on PDF...so on.
I know how to export whole Excel book to PDF but I can't specify which sheet needs to be exported to which page.
Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: I think you just need to adjust the print area on your excel sheet...I'd recommend posting this to [Super User](https://superuser.com/) with the `Excel` tag instead.

Comment: You can just move the sheets around in sequence that you need to be exported to PDF and then attempt the conversion.

Comment: As PankajR suggested you can first reorder the sheets per your requirement and then you can set each worksheet to fit on a single page, [see here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-a-worksheet-fit-the-printed-page-34a91eb5-8b4e-4a8a-ab28-b6492012eaae).